# Looking for a tool to read and query via X-Path large XML files

Tags: xml, windows, xpath

Hi I'm looking for an application which will open large xml files (50MB) AND which I can use X-Path queries. (For Windows)

[Free XML editor from First Object](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm) meets the first criteria, but not the second.

Cheers.
Murray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[First Object](http://www.firstobject.com/) meets the second criteria also but in a tricky way.
 You have to right click the xml expression in xml file window and in the context menu select "Generate Program"/"Gather Unique Values" . The FOAL program is generated in another window and in this you have to run in with F9 or the "Run" context menu item, select the xml file and, finally, you have the output !

Comment: Looks promising, but I haven't yet found any API documentation to help explain how I could alter the program to do other things.

Comment: Found it: http://www.firstobject.com/dn_markupmethods.htm

Comment: +1 +Answered. Nice one, seems very fast too (but there's a bit of extra work to get the program to output the details you may need.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well it works with large files, but [XML Notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7973) has some XPath capability.

Comment: +1 it's very very slow, but it eventually works :-] (P.S. I have 16Gig ram and XML is on SSD)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [XML XPath Visualizer Tool](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/).

I am using it and it's seems nice and it's a light weight application for Windows.

Comment: Looks nice, becomes unresponsive with a 50MB file tho :-] (reported: https://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/workitem/8942 )

Answer (score 1):

[Altova XmlSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) is a very powerful tool which has [support for XPath](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xpath-analyzer.html). It has XPath auto-completion and shows resulting node set at the time when you are typing your XPath query.

Comment: +1 Good but expensive. Fast opening, but slow performing xpath on 50MB file ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Traditional xpath engines create DOM from XML and evaluate xpath on that DOM. Creating DOM for 50MB xml files requires lot of memory.

You can try [XMLDog](http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XMLDog). it evaluates xpath on large xml files without creating DOM, thus requires little memory. It comes with a command line tool xmldog.bat.

It is implemented in java. So you can use it on windows

Answer (score 0):

50Mb is large, but well within the capacity of (say) Saxon. A lot depends on how you are using XPath: do you want to run more than one XPath query against the same document, for example? In that case, you almost certainly want the document in memory. In Saxon that will take about 250Mb, which is readily available on most modern machines. If you want to parse the XML from disk each time you run an XPath expression, then there may be processors that can do that (at least for a subset of XPath), but the parsing cost is likely to be high. As often happens, faster speed will cost more memory.

Comment: I have 16Gig of ram and the XML is read from SSD, yet most aplications fail (eg: IE is using nearly 2Gig or ram to try and display it (but it crashes) most/some other viewers have similar problems (the website I'm building to consume it is working fine ;-)

Comment: Why would you want to *display* 50Mb? No-one is going to read that much.

Comment: I want to browse/search it to ensure the data stored matches the data input or output

Answer (score 0):

I've used xmlstarlet before which enabled me to script the entire process.   Was hoping to find newer solutions to the problem, but this is the best of the list I see so far.

Comment: I have been using xmlstar, but ran into memory issue with a 3.75GB xml file.